# iOS: ViewDeck library and deleting row from UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, viewdeck

I'm using the [ViewDeck library](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) and order to have a sliding functionality in my app, and I run into the problem that if I have a `UITableView` in my left view controller and want to delete a row, I can't do it; it simply doesn't enter in the `commitEditingStyle`method.

Any idea please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you tired to see if ViewDesk is actually causing an issue? Seem's like this problem should be unrelated. How are you deleting the row? e.g. programmatically or based on user interaction?

Comment: @DanFairaizl I'm using the code in https://gist.github.com/noloman/5587465

Comment: Ok so how are you wanting to delete the row? Is the user deleting the row while the table is in edit mode?

Comment: @DanFairaizl thanks, I already answered.. my bad :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that I was returning NO in the method `canEditRowAtIndexPath`